# pd.DataFrame.to_csv saves values of dictionary as strings - why?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I created a DataFrame as you can following see:

[image]

[image]

The dictionary T14_dict is created before with:

```
T14_dict[energy_val] = (t, avg, avg)
```

The .csv-file contains values in this style:

```
energy,time,avg,avg_err
20.0,"[-0.1  -0.07 -0.04 -0.01  0.02  0.05  0.08  0.11  0.14  0.17  0.2   0.23
  0.26  0.29  0.32  0.35  0.38  0.41  0.44  0.47  0.5   0.53  0.56  0.59
  0.62  0.65  0.68  0.71  0.74  0.77  0.8   0.83  0.86  0.89  0.92  0.95
  0.98  1.01  1.04  1.07  1.1   1.13  1.16  1.19  1.22]","[         nan          nan          nan          nan          nan
          nan          nan          nan          nan  81.60226667
  93.53773333 103.138      115.2032     118.1768     126.75273333
 131.72366667 140.0756     141.1718     140.85166667 133.4242
 132.70533333 128.68753333 118.58       102.66013333  84.78213333
  61.89466667  46.36013333  42.25433333  40.90183333  34.925
  32.63866667  41.21        32.88133333  41.98133333  37.24933333
          nan          nan          nan          nan          nan
          nan          nan          nan          nan          nan]","[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          2.54885558  1.56757383  2.27496195
  2.61566338  4.25385947  7.57098313  7.91804542  7.10001277  8.66210802
  9.12148934 10.44828152 12.66369996 13.27703515 20.88428797 24.34579755
 22.6338197  21.08409827 18.2006732  15.05202971 13.89172437  3.75492336
  3.96613408  2.32278389  3.8531692   2.68856707  5.27346549  0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.        ]"
```

How can I save the dictionary in a .csv-file which contains list with float values rather than a string representation of a list?

Comment: it seems you have `numpy.array` in DataFrame. so convert them to normal list. Maybe you should assign `avg.tolist()` instead of `avg`

Comment: Hi, this is what you're supposed to do, I think: https://support.ptc.com/help/creo/creo_schem/usascii/index.html#page/Schematics_hc/About_Including_a_List_of_Values_in_a_CSV_File.html